# Allow decimal numbers and limit numbers before and after on <input type=“text”>

Tags: html, angular, web, frontend

I have an input type=" text" and I want to restrict the input of the users to purely numbers or numbers with decimals up to 2 decimal places.

I am asking for a price input.
I want to limit the input to 17 digits before the decimal and 2 digits after the decimal point

I wanted to avoid complex steps. Is there a way to do it?

Comment: you can use https://github.com/text-mask/text-mask/tree/master/angular2/ , sample at https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular2-text-mask

Answer (score 1):

give this a try , I'm limiting the input with maxlength and validating using a regex which you can test here: https://regexr.com/57rtg

```
<input type="text" pattern="^\d{0,17}$|(?=^.{0,20}$)^\d+\.\d{0,2}$" maxlength="20">
```